# How do you write a ESC character to be interpreted by echo?

Tags: bash

Is there a \ESC or something I can put so `echo` command can interpret it?

Where is a list of these commands, like `\t\n\r`, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you might have to pass the `-e` switch:

```
echo -e '\n\t\a'
```

you can find the list of interpreted escapes in `echo` manpage and `info` entry. This is for GNU coreutils `echo`, likely the one you are using:

```
   If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:

   \\     backslash

   \a     alert (BEL)

   \b     backspace

   \c     produce no further output

   \e     escape

   \f     form feed

   \n     new line

   \r     carriage return

   \t     horizontal tab

   \v     vertical tab

   \0NNN  byte with octal value NNN (1 to 3 digits)

   \xHH   byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)
```

Bash will replace `/bin/echo` with its own builtin, but all sequences above are interpreted.

**Note that Posix compliance does not require this**, so some shells will have partial or no  support for the `-e` flag and escaping, namely Debian/Ubuntu Dash, which is the default shell on those platforms. You will have to invoke `echo` as `/bin/echo` to avoid calling the builtin and make sure your `/bin/echo` can handle escapes.

Use `printf` if you need to write portable code.

Comment: dash seems to handle the escape characters even without `-e`.

Comment: @EtanReisner that's because `\n` and `\t` (and maybe some other sequence) are replaced directly in strings, `echo` itself does not support escapes. Try `echo -e '\x01'` and you will notice

Comment: That comment doesn't make any sense. If the shell does it directly in strings then `-e` can't be necessary. If the shell isn't doing it then echo can need `-e`. You can't have it both ways. Also see the section on echo in the dash [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash).

Comment: I checked better and [Dash builtin `echo` in Debian is compiled so that it does the expansion](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=550399), regardless of the shell already doing it between double quotes, in that you are right. But the comment does make sense, read it again: _some_ sequences (namely, `\n` and `\t`) are interpreted, not _all_ (in fact the manpage you linked says _"All other backslash sequences elicit undefined behaviour."_). Still, the `-e` switch is not supported.

Comment: If the shell already did the expansion in double quotes then echo wouldn't need to do it. And you could just drop `-e` entirely when using the escaped characters the shell understands. Which escapes do you believe that to be? Certainly not any of the ones in your list above.

Comment: @EtanReisner you are seeking a rationale where there is none. Both can perform an expansion because of historic reasons, there was no underlying design decision. Escape sequences in single quotes are expanded by echo (with or without flag, depending on the implementation), escape sequences in double quotes are expanded by the shell.

Comment: My main point is that I am unaware of any escape sequences that are expanded by the shell in double quotes. And a quick test fails to show any that operate that way in either bash or dash.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I was thinking about the ANSI-C quoting (see the other answer) and mistook it for double-quote escaping, which does not exist, you are absolutely right. My point was that both the shell and echo are able to perform escaping and there is no technical reason why this feature has been doubled.

Comment: +1 for the `printf` recommendation. Maybe make it more prominent?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using bash, it's probably better to use that shell's so-called ["ANSI-C Quoting"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html). This lets you construct a string that you can pass to the `echo` command, which will simply print it.

For example, to print an ASCII `ESC` character:

```
echo $'\e'
```

or

```
echo -n $'\e'
```

if you don't want the trailing newline.

(The term "ANSI-C Quoting is a bit of a misnomer for several reasons. The C standard is currently produced by ISO, not ANSI, and the bash feature supports `\e` and `\E` to represent the Escape character, and `\cX` for control-X, features not in standard C. The handling of hex escapes is also a bit different.)

Even better, you can use the `printf` command, which also supports `\e` for the `ESC` character. `printf` is far more portable that `echo`. There are a number of different versions of the `echo` command, both as `/bin/echo` and as built-in commands in most shells. `printf` also exists in multiple versions, but the behavior across implementations is much more consistent. Code using `printf` is more likely to be portable to shells other than bash (or to older versions of bash) than code that depends on any of the more arcane features of bash's `echo` command, or of the GNU coreutils `echo` command.